# Hibernate: Using singleton session to write log (no flush)

Tags: java, hibernate, session, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm considering using Singleton Session to write request log for our application.

Usually I would use Hibernate with Lifestyle PerWebRequest, but in my specific case there is no Http Context (we use socket thread to listen for request). However, I notice that, **as we only use the session to record log, I can use a *singleton* Hibernate session as well**.

Even if multiple threads run the session, all the request log will just add up in the session and get saved when Hibernate feels comfortable. There is no need to read the log **right after** it was written, so that would work.

The code would be something like this:

```
// Got socket request
// Doing some stuff here, saving to a legacy database (cannot use Hibernate with this one)

var logging = new Message(info);
loggingService.save(logging); // FYI: in case it fail, we don't want to roll back the previous work
```

The only concern I have is that, when we want to do load-balancing with 2 program running on multiple machine, then it could be a problem. I figure that in that case we must do some locking/synchronization to avoid possible conflicts (though I can't think of any for now).

Is it an ok use for Singleton session, or there are possible impacts that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

This "brilliant" idea of utilizing Singleton Session cost me quite a few days to clean up the mess. At first it produces good result, but then lots of unpredictable errors.

Now I can confirm Session isn't designed for something like this.
I'm opting to delete this question, but then decide to leave it here for anyone who have same "brilliant moments".

**TL;DR: I'd recommend everyone to stick with the "good old way": one thread - one session.**